# Ubuntu supervisord PYTHONPATH not getting set

Tags: python, ubuntu, supervisord

I'm having an issue with setting up the PYTHONPATH in supervisor, I'm setting the PYTHONPATH in the environment variables in the .conf file but it's as if supervisor isn't adding the variable.

```
[program:startup]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/application
directory=/home/ubuntu/application
user=ubuntu
command=/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/application/bin/python -u /home/ubuntu/application/tools/startup.py
process_name=%(program_name)s
stdout_logfile=/var/log/application/startup_output.log
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
autostart=true
autorestart=false
```

This error is returned regardless

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/startup.py", line 8, in <module>
    from app.bin.startup import Start
ImportError: No module named 'app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add quotation marks:

```
environment=PYTHONPATH="/my/path:$PYTHONPATH"
```

You should also preserve the existing value of `PYTHONPATH` (if any), which is what the above does.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of this problem by installing your application. Python packaging is [fairly easy](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html) in those cases when it works :)